# how do I group by a property of a related entity in a criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, projection

I'm writing a criteria that should group the results by a property of a related entity. I've tried using an alias, tried using the property path itself, but so far I get nothing.
say my classes are (rough sketch):

```
class A{
 @ManyToOne(...)
 B b;
}
class B{
 @OneToOne(...)
 C c;
}
class C{
 String s;
}
```

and I want a criteria that returns the amount of A's and B's for each unique string s in C.

my initial attempt was:

```
session.createCriteria(A.class)
  .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.groupProperty("b.c.s"), "string")
    .add(Projections.countDistinct("b"), "b's")
    .add(Projections.rowCount(), "a's"))
```

This didn't help much as b.c.s is not a property of A.

then I tried

```
session.createCriteria(A.class)
  .createAlias("b.c", "al")
  .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.groupProperty("al.s"), "string")
    .add(Projections.countDistinct("b"), "b's")
    .add(Projections.rowCount(), "a's"))
```

this actually was translated to SQL, but did not get far, as it did not include any joins in the query.

seems I am doing something wrong here.

Is it possible to get an efficient query of this kind using the criteria API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like this:

```
sess.createCriteria(A.class)
    .createCriteria("b")
    .createCriteria("c")
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.groupProperty("s"), "string")
    .list()
    .size()
```

i think you must look in double `createCriteria()`

Comment: yeah, i use this most of the time with two times, but with three times it must work the same. i didnt check the code above, but you can give it a try

Comment: I mean, I can't count the A's and B's in the same criteria? (10x for the answer, btw)

Comment: i think you can. you can make a projection, then count the list. then you can undo the projection with the resulttransformer

https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html